# Texting from ruby to a mobile phone

Tags: ruby, sms

Is there any way to set up ruby to send a text to a mobile phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/%20Twilio). They have perfect api and there is a [cool library that wraps this api](https://github.com/webficient/twilio)

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an american phone. http://www.twilio.com/faq/sms so it wont work.

Comment: Without US number you'll be able to send messages but not receive responses